React Native - Send value from textarea using WebView does not send data back when text pasted inside textarea
I have a WebView that contains a textarea but when I paste the data inside the textarea and send the text back to react native the text comes back as the previous text after the text was pasted.
So initially if I had some text in the textarea as "This is old text" when I paste the text such as "this is new text" the text return is "This is old text".
this is the code:
<WebView 
                        style={{flex:1,
                            marginTop:10,
                            width: '100%',
                            height: '100%',
                            fontSize:46,
                        }}
                        onMessage={(event) => {
                
                            
                            editorOnChange(event.nativeEvent.data);
                          }}
                        
                        source={{
                                html: `
                                        <!DOCTYPE html>
                                        <html>
                                            <head>
                                                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
                                                
                                            </head>
                                            <body>
                                            <style>
                                                    [contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
                                                        content: attr(data-text);
                                                        cursor: text;
                                                        color: red;
                                                        pointer-events:none;
                                                    }
                
                                                    #placeholder{
                                                        position:absolute;
                                                        
                                                        color:#BDBDBD;font-size:46px;outline:none;
                                                    }
                                                    #contentHtml{
                                                        font-size:38px;
                                                        word-wrap: break-word;
                                                        font-family: 'Roboto';
                                                        padding:8px;
                                                        outline:none;
                                                        border:none;
                                                        width:100%;
                                                        height:100vh;
                                                    }
                                                </style>
                                                <textarea id="contentHtml" maxlength="500" rows="20"  placeholder="Enter Comment...">${commentPlainText}</textarea>
                                                
                                                
                                            </body>
                                        </html>
                                        <script>
                                            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                                                
                                                $(document).on("keyup paste", "#contentHtml", function(e){
                                                    if(e.type === "paste"){
                                                        alert($(this).val());
                                                        setTimeout(function () {
                                                            alert($(this).val());
                                                            window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage($(this).val());
                                                        }, 100);
                                                    }else{
                                                        var contentValue = $(this).val();
                                                        window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(contentValue);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            });
                                            
                                        </script>
                                        `,
                            }}>
                
                
                
                        </WebView>

The output coming back is:
"This is old text"

This is the call back:
  const editorOnChange = (txt) => {
        console.log(txt);
  }


I basically changed the keyup event to input
$(document).on("**input** paste", "#contentHtml", function(e){

